# Combine Columns with same ID and search the data

Tags: sql

I have a table (tblABC) which looks like

```
-------------------------------
BasicID   | Filter1 | Filter2 |
-------------------------------
 100          1         2
 100          3         4
 101          8         9
```

What I want to do on it is - I want to select the BasicID which has Filter1=1 and Filter2=4. ie I want to get the output as
100

Can I create a view of something by combining the BasicID. Something that looks similar to

```
--------------------------------
BasicID   | Filter1|  Filter2 |
--------------------------------
 100          1,3         2,4
 101          8            9
```

Once this is done I can search using a simple search query like 
'select the BasicID tblNewlyCreatedTable where Filter1=1 and Filter2=4'
and get the output as 100.

To solve this issue I have tried the following methods all of which have failed me as it was not efficient because I have around 12 filter to filter on. Also not all of the filter will be applied all the time, at times it will be 4 filters, at times 2 and at time all 12.

1. select * from tblABC
   where 
   and BasicID in 
   (
   select BasicID from tblABC
   where Filter1 IN (1) 
   )
   and BasicID  in 
   (
   select BasicID from tblABC
   where Filter2 IN (4) 
   )

2.
using SELECT for finding the results individually for Filter1 and Filter2 using a INTERSECT to intersect them.

One more question I have is will creating another table where all Filter fields are varchar instead of int and then searching on the text be any good? I was advised by many to avoid this, as this will also cause efficiency problem. But would filtering on 12 varchar fields in the same select query be more efficient than, calling 12 select queries on int fields and combining them???

Comment: are you using `oracle`?

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL

```
SELECT BasicID, 
GROUP_CONCAT(FILTER1 ORDER BY FILTER1 ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS FILTER1,
GROUP_CONCAT(FILTER2 ORDER BY FILTER2 ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS FILTER2
FROM tblABC
GROUP BY BASICID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with filters as
(select 1 as val from dual union select 2 as val from dual
--add more values when needed 
)
select basicid from tblABC where Filter1 in (select val from filters)
intersect
select basicid from tblABC where Filter2 in (select val from filters)
```

This uses a `cte` with all the filter values.

Comment: Multiple Select queries were slowing down the response.. that is why I am looking for an alternative..

Comment: i don't think you will have a way to do it, without using the column names and filtering the values

Comment: what exactly do you mean by multiple `select` s?

Comment: 1. select basicid from tblABC where Filter1 in (select val from filters)
2. select basicid from tblABC where Filter2 in (select val from filters)

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to avoid that

Comment: having said that, why would you think it will slow down the response?

Comment: I did slow down the process. Some 15 secs for an API query.